# Старославянский, церковнославянский — предки русского языка или нет?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, история, славянизмы

В любой литературе можно найти сведения, что современный литературный русский язык испытал огромное влияние старославянского и/или церковнославянского. Однако после знакомства с лекцией уважаемого языковеда Зализняка (она была прочитана 24 февраля 2012 года в школе «Муми-тролль»), где он говорит, что

> > наш с вами литературный синтаксис гораздо более церковнославянский, чем русский

<..>

> > Русский литературный язык на каждом шагу пользуется синтаксическими приемами, которые в живом языке не встречаются, а идут из церковнославянского.

, у меня возник следующий вопрос. Ввиду того, что заимствования из старославянского и/или церковнославянского имеют столь фундаментальное значение в плане синтаксиса и большое по части грамматики и лексики, нет ли уважаемых языковедов, полагающих старославянский и/или церковнославянский предками современного русского языка наравне с древнерусским? Я бы хотел увидеть имена, названия трудов и, конечно, ваши личные мнения по этому поводу.

Comment: Пересвет, давайте определимся, Вы используете "старославянский" и "церковнославянкий" [язык] как синонимы? На этот счет есть разные мнения, не помню точно, но боюсь, что Зализняк принадлежит к той школе, которая разделяет эти понятия. Если так, то ваш вопрос становится не совсем корректным.

Comment: behemothus, я использую их как синонимы, так как сам не до конца понимаю разницу между ними. Для внесения ясности подправлю свой вопрос.

Comment: Понятно. Сеййчас попробую предварительно ответить, как я понимаю Зализняка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока очень кратко. Я не могу проверить или опровергнуть Зализняка насчет синтаксиса, но смысл высказывания постараюсь передать.
В одной их возможных терминологических систем рассматриваются **русский, древнерусский, старославянский** и **протославянский (гипотетический)**, а также **церковнославянский** (он же **древнеболгарский** - или его диалект),  который отнюдь не является предком древнерусского, но, как и русский, потомком старославянского (и/или) протославянского языка.

Грубо говоря, древнерусский и церковнославянский (=древнеболгарский) - два брата, два потомка одного  старославянского языка. Иногда говорят о **старославянском древнерусского извода** и, соответственно, **церковнославянского извода**.

Так вот, **древнерусский** на пути превращения в русский испытал огромное влияние не своего предка старославянского,  а именно родственного **церковнославянского** языка - сначала близкородственного, потом с течением времени ставшего уже скорее "двоюродным". Этот процесс волнообразно продолжался почти все время с момента появления христианства на Руси (а в чем-то рудиментарно продолжается и сейчас). При этом сам церковнославянский не стоял на месте, современный церковнославянский тоже несколько отличается от церковнославянского в его древнеболгарском состоянии.

Вот примерно о чем мог говорить Зализняк (не рискую утверждать наверняка).
Схемы мне рисовать сейчас не хочется, но если непонятно, нарисую. 
И, повторюсь, к этой терминологии могут быть различные подходы - и это сильно путает не только Вас.

Comment: behemothus, спасибо за ответ. Если Вы можете (и имеете на то время) более полно объяснить, то я только рад буду.
Но всё же тут нет ответа на главный вопрос. Есть ли уважаемые языковеды, которые возводили генетически русский не только к древнерусскому, но и к древнеболгарскому? То бишь приводили условную схему "древнеболгарский + древнерусский = русский"? Или наличие двух более-менее равноправных предков невозможно в принципе у естественных языков?

Comment: Нет, таких языковедов я не знаю. Те, кто употреблял (осознанно!) термин "древнеболгарский" делали это именно для того чтобы противопоставить его древнерусскому. А вообще надо контекст смотреть. Обычно разговоры о связи русского и ЦСЯ ведутся не в связи с проихосхождением, а именно в контексте влияния второго на первый. По части происхождения - там нет никаких практических вопросов. Ну были и были два (и больше) языка, чисто исторический вопрос. А вот последующее влияние - с ним приходится сталкиваться на каждом шагу, даже в вопросах правописания.

Comment: "Или наличие двух более-менее равноправных предков невозможно в принципе у естественных языков?" ----------  вполне возможно. Казахский, насколько знаю, таков. Но это очень отвлеченный вопрос, философский так сказать, да и не по теме ресурса.

Answer (score 1):

> > нет ли уважаемых языковедов, полагающих старославянский и/или церковнославянский предками современного русского языка наравне с древнерусским?

Боюсь, что все уважаемые языковеды как раз так и считают. И раньше считали. Это не Зализняк открыл.

Comment: Niemand, если все уважаемые языковеды так считают, то почему пласт древнерусских слов считаются исконными для современного русского (на правах наследования), а старославянизмы — заимствованиями?

Comment: Полагаю, что "исконные" - заимствованы так давно, что и не определить, откуда и когда, даже примерно.

Comment: Собственный опыт мне подсказывает, что "староболгарским" называют церковнославянский язык преимущественно украинские, идеологически заточенные "языковеды", особо подчеркивая, что в украинском языке в период его создания из народных домашних бесписьменных просторечий, удалось староболгарские элементы исключить из лексического массива. Таким образом, нынешний литературный украинский, вроде бы, более русский, чем русский, в котором всегда, по крайней мере с 10 века был книжный вариант, общерусский, старорусский - язык образованных людей, в котором было много лексики времен Кирилла и Мефодия.